# Upload to Rails Active Storage Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am attempting to upload an image to active storage in my Rails backend. I currently have the backend setup correctly but I am struggling to understand FormData. Here is what I have.

The on change function is listening for a change in the input which is of type 'file'. When I add the photo to the input I can get the info from e.target... However I don't know what to add as the URI here. The e.target.value here is a uri that is protected. So I'm confused about how this is supposed to work:

By the way, setFile is just setting 'file' to that object. I am using react.

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files)
    setFile({
        uri: e.target.value,
        name: e.target.files[0].name,
        type: e.target.files[0].type
    })
}

const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(file)

    let imageURI = file.uri
    let formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("image", { uri: imageURI, name: `${file.name}`, type: `${file.type}` })
    formdata.append("image", file)

    requests.postImageToCurriculum(66, formdata)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Active storage, use their js package

```
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage"

class Uploader {
  constructor(file, url) {
    this.upload = new DirectUpload(this.file, this.url, this)
  }

  upload(file) {
    this.upload.create((error, blob) => {
      if (error) {
        // Handle the error
      } else {
        // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form
        // with a value of blob.signed_id
      }
    })
  }

  directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request) {
    request.upload.addEventListener("progress",
      event => this.directUploadDidProgress(event))
  }

  directUploadDidProgress(event) {
    // Use event.loaded and event.total to update the progress bar
  }
}
```

[link here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)